# How to insert a specific value at the beginning of text in a Column using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert this character "-" at the beginning of each text in column F.

My F column looks like this:

```
BP850
BP851
BT100
GP160
GP161
```

I tried this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim str As String

'Change sheet if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find the last row of column F
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

'Loop column F
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            'Replace the first occurance
            str = Replace(.Range("F" & i).Value, "", "-", 1, 1)
            .Range("F" & i).Value = str
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

I expect:

```
-BP850
-BP851
-BT100
-GP160
-GP161
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using replace, just concatenate "-" before `str`

```
Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim str As String

'Change sheet if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find the last row of column F
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

'Loop column F
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            'Replace the first occurance
            str = "-" & .Range("F" & i).Value  '<== EDIT
            .Range("F" & i).Value = str
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your fast answare. I tried the code but is not really working. What I become from it is that: ` --
---
----
-----
------
-------
--------
--------- `

Comment: I think that there might be an issue with this because if you click on the cell and press enter, I think excel will turn that into a formula as it will become a reference to cell BP850. It might be good to add a single quote and dash instead of only a dash.

Comment: when you have for example '-BP850' try updating it to '-BP851' and see what happens

Comment: also happens even if you don't change the value. i.e. ie. when enter let's say the cell's edit mode

Comment: @SNicolaou, yes that's true, fair enough point! I'll also edit that into my own answer

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you could try to utilize `.Evaluate`. This prevents the need for any loop:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

'Change sheet if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find the last row of column F
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("F1:F" & LastRow)
        rng.Value = .Evaluate("""'-""&" & rng.Address)
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You don't even need to declare `str` since you're not using it =)

Comment: @M.Schalk, Forgot about it there since I copied code from OP. But you are right, not needed =)

Answer (score 2):

Your `str = Replace(.Range("F" & i).Value, "", "-", 1, 1)` has problem. Change it to following:

```
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        .Range("F" & i).Value = "-" & .Range("F" & i).Value
    Next i
```

No need to use `str` variable here.

Comment: I think that there might be an issue with this because if you click on the cell and press enter, I think excel will turn that into a formula as it will become a reference to cell BP850.

Comment: In such case you can simply put an additional space or single quote character before the dash (-)

Comment: a single quote is far better, that's what i proposed in my answer. An additional space is error prone as it is invisible :-)

Answer (score 2):

try this, ie. add "'-" in front of the value. Note the single quote before the -

```
For i = 1 To lastRow
  If .Range("F" & i).Value <> "" Then
    If Left(.Range("F" & i).Value, 1) <> "-" Then
      .Range("F" & i).Value = "'-" & .Range("F" & i).Value
    End If
  End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

See if following approach helps.
It will also check

1. Cell is not blank
2. Cell doesn't begin with "-"

which should help in case of accidental rerun of the macro!

```
Option Explicit

Sub test2()
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    'Change sheet if needed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find the last row of column F
         LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        'Loop column F
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If Len(.Range("F" & i).Value) > 0 And Left(.Range("F" & i).Value, 1) <> "-" Then _
            .Range("F" & i).Value = "-" & .Range("F" & i).Value
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim AdditionString As String, CellString As String, CompleteString As String

    AdditionString = "'-"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

         LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

         For i = 1 To LastRow

            CellString = .Range("A" & i).Value
            CompleteString = AdditionString & CellString
            .Range("A" & i).Value = CompleteString

         Next i

    End With

End Sub
```